# Building a webapp with two distinct user types - Should they be separate applications?

Tags: angularjs, heroku, architecture

I am building an Uber-like application, in that I have a 'Driver' and a 'Rider' type user. Currently I have an AngularJS web application, and a Node API from which the data for the app is served.

I have just now considered that it may be better to split out the 'Rider' and 'Driver' applications into two separate apps. I am using Heroku to host the applications, and ideally would like to have the urls for the applications to be driver.myapplication.com and myapplication.com.

I don't think that it's particularly straight forward to use a subdomain for some parts of the application, and it is instead much easier to just build the applications separately. Does it make sense to do it this way? I also then unluck the benefit of being able to scale the applications independently, although I think the overall spending on Heroku will rise slightly.

This also has the added benefit of making the individual code bases smaller, and easier for developers to understand. I think I'm right on this, but I just want an expert opinion.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the same for both users. The difference should be handle differents views through routing and user roles. For AngularJS you can use [Permission](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission). I think that is more easy maintain one App instead of two and avoid to use again the same libraries.

Good luck!

Comment: Why do you suggest that? Looking at Uber's web apps, they look completely separate. The two web apps would be linked through the API. Otherwise, I can't really host one at a subdomain, can I?